# Hub Section Relative Placement c# Windows Universal App?

Tags: c#, windows, controls, win-universal-app

This may seem rather basic, but I'm not well-versed in Windows Universal Apps yet, so maybe somebody could clear this up for me real fast. if I create a hub in a Windows Universal App in XAML, and then create children hub section classes, each successive hub section anchors itself exactly to the right of the previous hub section child. This, in effect creates a row of hub sections If i were to create a bunch of child hub sections and leave them at point (0,0) relative to their anchor point. This creates the issue obviously that if I have more than a few hub sections, it makes the page unnecessarily wide and I can't make multiple rows efficiently. So where can I find the anchor point for each hub section so it doesn't always place itself relative to the previous hub sections anchor? Thanks ahead of time for any help you guys can give.